# showing error in java

Tags: java

I want to create an application that shows a user how many times he opened or used the software. For this I have created the code below. But it is not showing correct output: when I run the application first it is showing `1` and then the second time I run it it is also showing `1`.

```
public Founder() {
    initComponents();

    int c=0;
    c++;
    jLabel1.setText(""+c);
    return;
}
```

Comment: @rmlan So have  you code for it .? I am doing netbeans

Comment: So you are also misunderstanding how this site works. We are not a code writing service.

Comment: I want to improve my code . I asked you the error coming in this code and it is not working so if you found an error in this code please update the code , I am not demand you for your own code here. I am not misunderstand about this website.

Comment: And why do you think your program has any chance to remember the last run? You even explicitly set the counter to 0 and increase it by 1.

Comment: when I try to return c; it is showing an error incompatible types: unexpected return value .

Comment: @rmlan, I believe it’s a valid constructor for a class violating the naming conventions by being named `founder` with a small f (class names should begin with a capital letter).

Comment: Well, the new issue you've mentioned just shows that you're missing basic knowledge about Java and how it works. You should work on that first. Read some basic books and tutorials. Then you can come back to this task and try again. AND stop adding unrelated tags -.-

Comment: @OleV.V. I update the code . Please give me a proper solution for it

Comment: Thanks for correcting the class name. I have no better solution that Anand Kumar’s answer.

Comment: @OleV.V. - Good point. I had not considered this. The naming and superfluous return statement threw me off.

Comment: I don’t think the fact that you are using Netbeans is relevant. The problem is the same no matter which IDE you use. If you think it *is* relevant, mention it in the question body, not just in the tags.

Comment: @OleV.V. if any time you got the answer please share here thank u

Comment: "I am not misunderstand about this website." -> "@OleV.V. if any time you got the answer please share here thank u" Yep, you know exactly how this place works.

Comment: @rmlan Here i am not mentioned any negative thing. If any  any time any peoples will get answer and they will update here. I also done same and those peoples are very helpful for it. I am not demand or ruled here to mentioned to create an output, I am just ask him only....

Comment: @rmlan you may also done some helps to the members in this group with properly so it may be help those peoples ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m unsure whether I’m helping you or giving you a load of new problems and unanswered questions. The following will store the count of times the class `Founder` has been constructed in a file called `useCount.txt` in the program’s working directory (probably the root binary directory, where your `.class` files are stored). Next time you run the program, it will read the count from the file, add 1 and write the new value back to the file.

```
static final Path counterFile = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("useCount.txt");

public Founder() throws IOException {
    initComponents();

    // read use count from file
    int useCount;
    if (Files.exists(counterFile)) {
        List<String> line = Files.readAllLines(counterFile);
        if (line.size() == 1) { // one line in file as expected
            useCount = Integer.parseInt(line.get(0));
        } else { // not the right file, ignore lines from it
            useCount = 0;
        }
    } else { // program has never run before
        useCount = 0;
    }
    useCount++;

    jLabel1.setText(String.valueOf(useCount));

    // write new use count back to file
    Files.write(counterFile, Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(useCount)));
}
```

It’s not the most elegant nor robust solution, but it may get you started. If you run the program on another computer, it will not find the file and will start counting over from 0.

Answer (score 1):

When you are running your code the first time, the data related to it will be stored in your system's RAM. Then when you close your application, all the data related to it will be deleted from the RAM (for simplicity let's just assume it will be deleted, although in reality it is a little different).

Now when you are opening your application second time, new data will be stored in the RAM. This new data contains the starting state of your code. So the value of c is set to 0 (c=0).

If you want to remember the data, you have to store it in the permanent storage (your system hard drive for example). But I think you are a beginner. These concepts are pretty advanced. You should do some basic programming practice before trying such things.

Comment: I already done C=0 . But it is still  not showing the correct output.

Comment: Have you understood my answer?

Comment: So you are thinking that to create a database ?

Comment: A database would be an option. I definitely think it falls under the answer’s “These concepts are pretty advanced. You should do some basic programming practice before trying such things.”

Comment: @OleV.V. when I check i found the same  in Android apps also. It is also showing some codes. But those codes are not will work in Netbeans

Comment: You could try to store data in a file and access it through your code. I think this might be possible but I don't have experience in doing it. So I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to store it on permanent basic.

1. Refer properties class to store data permanently:   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html
2. You can also use data files ex. `*.txt`, `*.csv`
3. Serialization also provide a way for persistent storage.
   You can create a class that implements Serializable with a field for each piece of data you want to store. Then you can write the entire class out to a file, and you can read it back in later.Learn about serialization here:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: ok. thank you , so if there is without a database any options are available ?

Comment: For these options we dont need to create database.